# VS Team Services and Azure Continuous delivery subdirectory

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-web-app-service, continuous-deployment, azure-devops

I have a project in VS Team Services git repository with the following structure (simplified):

- /

  - scripts (for typescript)
  - styles (for sass)
  - wwwroot (public directory with images, css, js...)
  - ...

All typescript and sass files are built with gulp into appropriate directory inside wwwroot.

What I'd like to do but can't find how, push only `wwwroot` directory to Azure Website instead of entire project.

If not possible, what are alternatives?

Comment: Thanks! I replaced VS Online with VS Team Services. Maybe I'll get used to the new name in the near future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways you could do this

**The Easier Way**

You can add a custom deployment setting that sets your wwwroot directory as the root directory for your site.

The bottom part of this post describes how to do this: http://www.zainrizvi.me/2015/10/13/deploy-statically-generated-sites-to-azure-web-apps/

Here's the relevant snippet:

> Add a .deployment file to the root folder of your code and paste the
>   below inside:
>
> `[config] 
>   project = wwwroot`

**The Harder Way**

If you really wanted to just deploy the wwwroot folder, you could use [Custom Deployment Scripts](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script) to deploy just the desired files to your site.

This involves creating a custom script that executes every time you deploy your site, and in that script you'll tell it to copy just the wwwroot folder over.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check that. I also found [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/azure/nodejs) which would also be great for me, but will Azure correctly detect it as check-in (for staging etc.)? (In my test scenario it doesn't)

My repo is quite large because of some additional assets and would like to avoid copying half of GB of files which aren't necessary.