# Azure Continuous Delivery - How to deploy a folder to an App Service?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, continuous-deployment

I'm pretty sure i am doing something wrong.
But let me attempt to explain my situation...

I created an Azure App Service with Continuous Delivery configured. So far i see that all my deployments are successful. When i go to my app service URL i see **Service Unavailable**.

Now i suspect my problem could be related to what is being deployed. 
Note that I am using Visual Studio Online for my source control and build system.

The source/repo only has 3 folders:

```
 - A folder called .vscode    

 - A folder called Tools (a bunch of .net console apps)    

 - A folder called Service (my node.js based service)
```

Now, the source builds successfully.
And the continuous deployment, triggered after a queued build, completes successfully.
But when i go to the service url i see the dreaded message "Service Unavailable".

**I suspect the problem is related to this:**

```
Basically im not sure what is being deployed here. 
What i want to deploy is just the Service folder (my node.js app). 
I suspect somehow that the entire source tree is being deployed.
```

Some additional details:

```
Http Protocol: HTTPS
Error: 503 - Service Temporarily Unavailable
```

Any help/insights are much appreciated!

**Updates**
I am confused if the Continuous Delivery option can deploy the node.js app. I did come across this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-nodejs) which shows how to deploy node.js app via "Push to Azure from Git".

**Updates 2**
I'm not entirely sure right now because i havent tried this out. But the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33495670/vs-team-services-and-azure-continuous-delivery-subdirectory) seems to hold the key (it seems like it is exactly what im looking for).

**Updated 3**
I was able actually get the node.js app to start. The issue was that the .js file is two folders deep (in the Service folder). I updated the "Startup command" setting under the "Deploy Azure App Service" (under Continuous Delivery build definition). Now i can see (from the Kudu Docker logs) that it is running.

The problem im having now is that the node.js app can't seem to conenct to the Azure SQL database (this works when i run locally).

Comment: Have you gone to your SCM site and looked to see what files actually exist on the server post-deployment?

Comment: @Rob - What is SCM site? Do you mean Azure?

Comment: FYI - I found a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33495670/vs-team-services-and-azure-continuous-delivery-subdirectory

Comment: A SCM site is the companion site that runs Kudu and any other site extensions you have installed. Among other things, it will show processes that are running, and let you browse and interact with files deployed to your Web App. I suggest logging in using your Azure Portal credentials and browsing files to ensure what you thought was deployed is actually deployed. The url for your SCM site is https://[your site name].scm.azurewebsites.net.

Comment: Deep inside the Continuous Delivery configuration i found a setting called "Deploy Azure App Service". Under here there is a field called "Package or folder" which contains the value: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip     . Is there a way to specify the subfolder here (instead of the zip file)?

Comment: btw, i looked at the SCM site. i dont see much relevant details here (not much stuff under the Files link).

Comment: I was however able to see that there is Docker logs. From here i was able to get some details why the node.js app failed to run.